# Como criar funções para extensão

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extensão

Eu estou criando uma extensão, minha primeira extensão para o Google Chrome, a extensão consiste em alterar elementos de uma página qualquer e mudar coisas, mas queria colocar uma função para um botão via `onclick`, mas não funciona!
Supondo que no site tem a seguinte estrutura `HTML:`

```
<button class="one" onclick="funcaoOriginal();">Teste</button>
```

No arquivo `js` da extensão tenho o seguinte:

```
function minhaFuncao(){
alert('teste');
}

$('.one').attr('onclick','minhaFuncao()');
```

mas não funciona!, se for assim:

```
$('.one').attr('onclick','alert(\'teste\')');
```

Ele funciona, mas quero colocar coisas como `$.each` e `$.cookie` dentro de uma função e chamar ela ao clicar no botão do site.

Como eu faria isso?

Comment: Onde tens essa `minhaFuncao()` no código? está no escopo global ou dentro de outra função como `.ready()`?

Comment: E porque não usar `$('.one').on('click', minhaFuncao);`?

Comment: Dentro do `.ready()` @Sérgio, eu tentei `$('.one').click(function(){ //codigo });` e funcionou! não tinha pensado antes. muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando tens chamadas de funções *inline* no HTML então essas funções têm de estar no escopo global. Se colocares dentro de uma outra função como o `.ready()` então elas ficam só acessíveis dentro dessa função e não mais no escopo global.

Tens duas alternativas:

- colocar no escopo global e manter a chamada à função *inline* no HTML

HTML:

```
<button class="one" onclick="funcaoOriginal();">Teste</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function minhaFuncao(){
    // fazer algo
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    // resto do código...
```

- usar um oscultador de evento

Nesse caso poder retirar `onclick="funcaoOriginal();"` do HTML e usar

```
 $('.one').on('click', function(){
     // código
 });
```

ou usando a função declarada à parte

```
$('.one').on('click', minhaFuncao);
```

Esta segunda alternativa é melhor. Misturar JavaScript *inline* no HTML não é boa solução. Se usares `$('.one').on('click', minhaFuncao);` lembra-te que esta linha e a declaração da função têm de estar no mesmo escopo. Podem estar ambas dentro do `.ready()` ou noutro bloco do código, mas têm de estar no mesmo escopo.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação Sergio.